# Force str.format() to use two digits when displaying hexadecimals

Tags: python, format

I have the following line of code:

```
print "{: ^#6x}".format(val),
```

which (in part) produces the following output:

```
0x1    0x0    0x0    0x0
0x3    0xb2   0x0    0x0
0x3    0x0    0x3    0x0
0x2b   0x0    0x0    0x0
0xb    0x0    0xb    0x0
0x20   0x0    0x0    0x0
```

This is all fine and dandy, but to help things line up and look better I would like to force the hexadecimal numbers to all be two digits, i.e. `0x00`. However, when I try to add precision to the format specifier, i.e. `{: ^#6.2x}`, it gives me the error:

> ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier

How can I force the hexadecimals to always display two digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `#04x` to pad the output to 2 digits with a `0x` prefix, then format that again to fit your 6-character width:

```
print format(format(val, '#04x'), '^6'),
```

I used the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) instead since you are not interpolating into a larger string.

Since now the field is going to be 4 characters wide, always, you can also just hardcode the two spaces padding with a string format:

```
print ' {:#04x} '.format(val),
```

Demo:

```
>>> format(3, '#04x')
'0x03'
>>> format(format(3, '#04x'), '^6')
' 0x03 '
>>> ' {:#04x} '.format(3)
' 0x03 '
```